# PHP Array empty when in external script, normal when in file

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

Hard to explain - I'm using AJAX to help me with a filtering system on some XML data. Here's my AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
method: 'POST',
url: '../inc/gun_fetcher.php',
data: {
  find_and_return:'ALL',
  'ajax': true
},
success: function(data) {
  $('#gun_holder').html(data);
  console.log(data);
}
});
```

(bear in mind, I'm not filtering anything yet - I'll work on that once this is working full stop) - and here's the important part of my gun_fetcher.php file:

```
$gun_e = (""."<div class='gun_listing'>"."<h2>".$make." ".$mode."</h2>"."<span id='gun_price'><p>£".$pric."</p></span>".$im_a[0]['f'].implode("",$im_t)."</div>"."");

array_push($guns_finished,$gun_e);

echo count($guns_finished);
```

Now, the problem.

If I just stick my PHP code onto the page, I can output the array (I'm using count() for now, just for ease-of-reading) as expected. However, once I move it into the external file and call to it with AJAX, I get 0 returned from the count.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE | FULL GUN_FETCHER.PHP**

```
<?php 
$feed = file_get_contents('https://3rdparty.guntrader.uk/OrstonShootingGround/xmlGuns');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($feed);
$guns = $xml->guns->gun;
$startPage = $_GET['page'];
$perPage = 9;
$currentRecord = 10;
$totalRecords = $guns->count();
$guns_finished = [];
foreach($guns as $gun){
    $i = 0;
    $im_a[] = "";
    $im_t[] = "";
    $type = $gun -> type;
    $mech = $gun -> mechanism;
    $cali = $gun -> calibre;
    $make = $gun -> make;
    $mode = $gun -> model;
    $vari = $gun -> variant;
    $orig = $gun -> origin;
    $orie = $gun -> orientation;
    $barr = $gun -> barrelLength;
    $bari = $gun -> barrelLengthInches;
    $stoc = $gun -> stockLength;
    $scle = $gun -> scopeLength;
    $scmk = $gun -> scopeMake;
    $scmg = $gun -> scopeMag;
    $summ = $gun -> summary;
    $cond = $gun -> condition;
    $pric = $gun -> price;
    $expd = $gun -> expiryDate;
    $imgc = $gun -> imageCount;
    $stkn = $gun -> stockNumber;
    $prdg = $gun -> pairedGun;
    $srnu = $gun -> serialNumber;
    $imgs = $gun -> images;
    foreach($imgs -> image as $img) {
            $n = $img -> number;
            $f = "<img src='".$img -> fullPath."' alt='".$make." ".$mode."' />";
            $t = "<img class='thumbnail' src='".$img -> thumbPath."' />";
            $im_a[$i] = array('n' => $n, 'f' => $f, 't' => $t);
            foreach($t as $t){
                $im_t[$i] = $t."' />";
            }
            $i++;
    }
    if(count($imgs) === 0){
        $im_a[0]['f'] = "<img src='http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/no-image-icon-15.png' />";
    }
    $lice = $gun -> licence;
    $crea = $gun -> created;
    $modi = $gun -> modified;
    if(($currentRecord > ($startPage * $perPage) && $currentRecord <= ($startPage * $perPage + $perPage)) || ($startPage == 1)&&($currentRecord === 10)){
        $gun_e = (""
        ."<div class='gun_listing'>"
        ."<h2>".$make." ".$mode."</h2>"
        ."<span id='gun_price'><p>£".$pric."</p></span>".
        $im_a[0]['f'].
        //."<img class='thumbnail' src='".
        implode("",$im_t)
        .""
        .""
        ."</div>"
        ."");
        array_push($guns_finished,$gun_e);
        unset($im_a);
        unset($im_t);
    }
        $currentRecord += 1;
    }
    for ($i = 1; $i <= ($currentRecord / $perPage); $i++) {
       echo("<a href='/gun_feed/?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>");
    }
        echo count($guns_finished);
        echo json_encode($guns_finished);
?>
```

Comment: done any basic debugging, like adding an `error` handler to your ajax call? You're just ASSUMING nothing will ever go wrong.

Comment: paste full  gun_fetcher.php content

Comment: @MarcB, the most debugging I've done is finding that the array is totally empty when called in from externally, and not when called in from in the main file.

Comment: In your ajax, your using POST, but in your file, you have `$startPage = $_GET['page'];` without sending that GET parameter. That should give you an "undefined index"-error. If it doesn't, you should turn "display_errors" on while developing, or check your web servers error log.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Awesome! I had to fix a couple of invalid foreach issues, but you're right - thanks for the help, any tips on fixing it? Would you like to post your comment as an answer, by the way, so that I can accept it?